# sqlite3 get number of day and week python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, sqlite

I would like to get numbers of day and week (set up Wednesday as first day of week).I use `sqlite3` to create database.

sample database`Order`

```html
name  time
A0001 10/1/16
A0002 10/2/16
A0003 10/5/16
A0004 10/16/16
A0005 10/8/16
A0006 10/17/16
A0007 10/23/16
```

```html
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

%sql sqlite://
select name, strftime('%w',time) as weekday,strftime('%W',time) as weeknumber
from Order
```

It seems like `strftime` did not work.All `weekday` and `weeknumber` returns to `None`

Comment: `strftime()` is returning null because `'10/1/16'` etc. is not a date format that it recognizes. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: And since I don't want to type it out again today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917975/9952196

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before too. It is caused DBMS can't recognize this date string format. I resolved this by using one of the sqlite date formats:
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

If your have many records in the table, you can write a script which reformats all your records. Otherwise you can just fulfil the table again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dateutil parser to convert the dates in your text file into a standard format.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> for line in open('rya.txt'):
...     line = line.strip()
...     
...     item = line.split()
...     print(item[0], str(parse(item[1])).split()[0])
...     
A0001 2016-10-01
A0002 2016-10-02
A0003 2016-10-05
A0004 2016-10-16
A0005 2016-10-08
A0006 2016-10-17
A0007 2016-10-23
```

Having done that, you could use datetime to obtain the weekday number and the week number for each.

Alternatively you could apply similar logic using a Python function to the database table itself.